# What's considered to be better design here?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, architecture

I hope this isn't too subjective. I can't decide between these two design opportunities.

I have a Front Controller pattern. When the user surfs to a specific URL, my framework loads a specified View Controller for this URL. The View Controller then calculates some things and loads a View Template, to show the results.

Now imagine you wanted to make a site like SO. Every page looks pretty similar: Same header, same menu, same footer. Just the content area is different. You surf to the "Ask Question" page, and want the "Ask new Question" form to come up inside the layout.

So we make a `RootViewController` with a `RootView` template that sets up the layout and has a placeholder for the content. And a `AskQuestionViewController` with an `AskQuestionView` template.

Our Front Controller loads the `AskQuestionViewController` class. The system calls the `loadView()` method, and then the `viewDidLoad()` method.

### Option A: `AskQuestionViewController` inherits from `RootViewController`.

method gets called by the system, and calls `parent::loadView()` first. So `RootViewController` gets the chance to create its `RootView` template. Next, `loadView()` loads the `AskQuestionView` template, and assigns it to the content placeholder of the `RootView` template.

### Option B: `AskQuestionViewController` does not inherit from `RootViewController`.

The `loadView()` method of `AskQuestionViewController` loads `RootViewController` first. Then it loads its own `AskQuestionView` template, and assigns it to the content placeholder of the `RootView` template.

The only differences between these View Controllers are, that they load different View templates, and that they have different custom methods to perform certain tasks. i.e. the `RootViewController` is able to compose the Navigation Menu and highlight what's currently visited. There's nothing else in `RootViewController` that could be useful for `AskQuestionViewController`.

Which Option would be better design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [prefer composition over inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx) principle suggests **B** is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

The `AskQuestionViewController` is not really a specialisation of the `RootViewController`. So, I'd definitely say B. It may make sense for the two controllers to both inherit from a common parent class.

Comment: indeed there's an abstract ViewController parent class for every View Controller :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer in a general, platform independant manner, but i'd go with B.